# How to connect two line segments without changing their directions in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Say I have two line segments with different slopes, one has `x` ranging from -0.5 to -0.1, the other has `x` ranging from 0 to 0.5. I want to use matplotlib to plot the two line segments into one line by connecting the two line segments. This is my current code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-0.5, 0.51, 0.1)
y1 = np.linspace(2, 10.5, 5)
y2 = np.linspace(11, 1, 6)
plt.ylim([0, 14])
plt.plot(x, np.concatenate([y1,y2]), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

This will produce the following plot
[image]

However, what I want is to extend the two line segments until their intersection. The expected plot looks something like below
[image]

I want a general solution, which can generate such plot that connects any two given line segments `y1` and `y2`. Note that I only want to have 11 markers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (and format it better if you need) :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress

def line_intersect(m1, b1, m2, b2):
    x = (b2 - b1) / (m1 - m2)
    y = m1 * x + b1
    return x,y

x = np.arange(-0.5, 0.51, 0.1)
y1 = np.linspace(2, 10.5, 5)
y2 = np.linspace(11, 1, 6)

y1_lin = linregress(x[:2], y1[:2])
y2_lin = linregress(x[-2:], y2[-2:])

intersection_point = line_intersect(y1_lin.slope, y1_lin.intercept, y2_lin.slope, y2_lin.intercept)
x3 = np.array([x[0], intersection_point[0], x[-1]])
y3 = np.array([y1[0], intersection_point[1], y2[-1]])



plt.ylim([0, 14])
plt.plot(x, np.concatenate([y1,y2]), marker='o', color='blue', linestyle='None')
plt.plot(x3, y3, marker='', color='blue')
plt.show()
```

And that shows this:
[image]

Basically, all that is happening is I calculate where the two lines intersect and use that to create a small new x, y mapping with 3 data points, the middle being the intersection point and the other ones the endpoints of the x.